# OCSP responder that returns embedded SCTs

Tags: ocsp, certificate-transparency, sct

There are three ways for a TLS client to obtain Signed Certficiate Timestamps (SCTs):

1. During the TLS handshake itself using the SCT List extension
2. As embedded precertificate SCTs in the leaf certificate
3. As embedded SCTs in a stapled OCSP response using an OCSP extension (OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.5).

**Question:** Is there any publicly-trusted CA, that has an OCSP responder that serves SCTs embedded into OCSP responses? It seems like [Comodo once did this](https://blog.pierky.com/certificate-transparency-manually-verify-sct-with-openssl/), but is no longer doing it.